# For a SciPy sparse matrix, how to get indices of values below a threshold

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

When using a conditional statement to filter values in a SciPy sparse array, how can I get the indices of those values?

I am trying to use apply the conditional statement to `csc_array().data` to get the indices but they don't match the `csc_array().nonzero()` indices.  Here is an example of the issue I am facing:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_array, csc_array

m = dok_array((1000, 1000))
for i, j in zip(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100), np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100)):
    m[i, j] = np.random.random()

threshold = 0.3
tmp = csc_array(m)
mask = tmp.data < threshold
i, j = tmp.nonzero()
i_mask, j_mask = i[mask], j[mask]
assert np.alltrue(tmp[i_mask, j_mask] < threshold), "This fails!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around the mis-match between the ordering of `csc_array().data` and `csc_array().nonzero()`, you can simply use the `nonzero` indices throughout, as shown here:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_array, csc_array

m = dok_array((1000, 1000))
for i, j in zip(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100), np.random.randint(0, 1000, 100)):
    m[i, j] = np.random.random()

threshold = 0.3
tmp = csc_array(m)
i, j = tmp.nonzero()
mask = tmp[i, j] < threshold
i_mask, j_mask = i[mask], j[mask]
tmp[i_mask, j_mask] = 0
tmp.eliminate_zeros()
assert np.alltrue(threshold < tmp.data), "Should not see this!!!" 

m = dok_array(tmp)
```